# Using a TP4056 with a 08570 Battery

Tags: battery-charging, safety, charger, protection, charge

Will a TP4056 (the ones with mini USB and no battery protection) charge a 08570 battery safely?

From what I can tell the battery does have built in battery protection but I cannot find much information about it.

The battery is 3.7v and falls within the parameters to be used, but I'm not sure if it will work safely with this specific battery.

Comment: "falls within the parameters to be used" - which are?

Comment: Be a rechargable 3.7v li-ion / li-po battery

Comment: Capacity? Maximum charge current?

Comment: The 08570 that I'm using is 1.1wh and the tp4056 max charge current is 1a

Comment: Yes, I know that TP4056 modules typically charge at 1A. What is the maximum permitted charge current for your **battery**?

Comment: My bad, the data sheet I found says 3.0A